# Wake on WAN refusing to work. WOL works

Tags: internet, port-forwarding, port, wake-on-lan

Trying to setup WoW and I'm running out of ideas. I can wake it up on LAN so I know PC is setup right. I have forwarded ports 7,9 and 4343. Put in DMZ. I have tested when PC is on it does receive the packet using a sniffer. So I'm at a loss as to why it doesn't turn on. When I try to test if the ports are open it Open Port checker says all my forwarded ports are closed. Even port 80 which is weird. I also have removed the tick from the net adapted to wake up ONLY on magic packets in the NAT configuration. Any ideas? I'm using a Hitron CGNM-2250 router. Could it be that it's just not doing its job properly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to send a WoL broadcast frame across a router? That won't work since broadcasts are stopped at layer-3 boundaries.

The way to implement WoL across different networks is to set up a WoL server on each subnet, and send a layer-3 message to it to send the WoL magic packet (really a magic frame) out on the server's layer-2 domain.

Comment: So the only way to wake up my PC is to have a dedicated machine running 24/7 on my network?

Comment: You can try to forward the traffic to your subnet broadcast address. It is highly dangerous to allow outside users to broadcast on your network since broadcasts must be received and processed by every host on the network, which is one of the reasons broadcasts are limited to the layer-2 domain.

Comment: There are instruction for doing something so dangerous at this site, but most companies wishing to do this use a WoL server on each layer-2 domain: http://www.howtogeek.com/192642/how-to-remotely-turn-on-your-pc-over-the-internet/

Comment: Would it be better to buy a router that has a WoL capability? And are there some like that out there? I've heard of dd-wrt custom software for the router that has a functionality like that if I'm not mistaken. Since if I have to get something to be on all the time it might as well be my router

Comment: It would be much safer to have a router which understands WoL and can do that specifically rather than allowing anyone to send broadcasts to your LAN. It still poses some risk that anyone in the world can send WoL messages to the hosts on your network, but the risk is much less.